# Execute multiple asserts in a single test - soap ui

Tags: unit-testing, soap, groovy, soapui, soap-client

I am new to `SoapUI`. I have a test suite with single test step. My test step has two assertions in groovy script.

```
assert id== '123' : "id value not valid"
assert no== '12' : "no not valid"
```

If 1st assertion fails, the test stops and the next assertion is not executed.

Is there a way so that even if the 1st assertion fails, remaining assertions continue and after all the assertions are executed and then test stops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different questions!

First, if you have multiple test steps and you want to not stop at the first error, you can turn off the "Abort on Error" option in the testcase options; this option is on by default. This is discussed more in the [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/testcase-execution.html).

Second, if you have **one** script assertion, as you have shown, and you want to execute the entire script, then this is a Java problem. By definition, the first `assert` statement that fails will stop the script. You will need to rewrite your script in some other fashion. Maybe:

```
def errors = 0
if(id != '123') {
    log.error "id value not valid"
    errors++
}
if(no != '12') {
    log.error "no not valid"
    errors++
}
assert errors == 0
```